# Bootstrap Twitter and Less.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

in the latest version of bootstrap(2.0.1) and in the latest version of less.js (1.2.1) I get errors. What is the current state of this issue? Will it be fixed in the next releases?

Comment: Add more details about the error you are getting. It's the only way we can attempt to even guess.

Comment: You are right, check the github link : https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2220#issuecomment-4164044